# Suddenly App Logs Out: "Root view controller at the end of application launch"

Tags: ios, storyboard

i was just writing my App and suddenly my App Logs Out:

> Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

I thought i could be something i wrote in the last minute so i pressed "cmd + z" to go back! But the log does not disappear. So i looked up for that issue and they said i should add this to my AppDelegate.m:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController
```

I added a property to AppDelegate.h:

```
@property ViewController *viewController;
```

That is my AppDelegate.m at this moment:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Okay with that solution it worked, but not correct. The background Image stayed also the UIView's but all Labels are gone. What should I do?

Comment: Try with     `self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
`

Comment: Okay sorry for my last comment, it worked. But i try to understand why does the app suddenly need that?

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I am using Storyboard

Comment: I did but getting Error

Comment: if you are using the storyboard, you don't need to instantiate a view controller. just `return YES;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load you viewcontroller using **instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier**,

Use this in appdelegate

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                         bundle: nil];
self.viewController =(ViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ViewController"];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
return YES;
```

NOTE: Make sure you give correct identifier name,

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x16e92eb0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'ViewController''

Comment: @user3123470: As i said please give correct identifier name.you are giving wrong identifier name.

Comment: @user3123470: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8315472/1597744 check this for set your viewcontroller identifier from storyboard.

Comment: Yes I understood. I tried every name, but i does not work. My ViewController ist called "ViewController"

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/8315472/1597744 this way ? here set you identifier to **ViewController**.

Comment: Yes I did, but I am using a ViewController, there is no section for "Identifier" only Titel. There is a section under it, called Initial Scene, but it is on.

Comment: go to story board, select your viewcontroller and set it,
http://i.imgur.com/z3Isf6x.png

Comment: @user3123470: check http://i.imgur.com/z3Isf6x.png image and according to it set.

Comment: Thanks for that Foto, so i entered "ViewController" but same error, i copied the name of ViewController in the Class Section beyond it. There are no typo failures. But it does not work. (Just for a trie I also entered "Main" Storyboard Name, as well, also entered "Main.storyboard" same error)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i don't understand either. It just happened, the app was working fine 3Minutes before that! But you're first solution is working fine: This one: self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]; [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];