# Can't find Storyboard ID in Identity inspector

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, storyboard, xcode5

I'm trying to find the "Storyboard ID" which should be before Restoration ID in Identity inspector, but I can't find that for any view I've selected. I've tried to open a new project and I still can't find it either.

[image: Identity inspector]

I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 developing for iOS-7.

Can you tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295471/storyboard-doesnt-contain-a-view-controller-with-identifier

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

You are pointing to a `UIView` or some other object on the StoryBoard. Press the yellow indicator on top of the other objects which is your `ViewController`

Comment: So it's not possible to get a specific view by some uniqe ID? (I though each view has a storyboard ID).

Comment: @uriel only `ViewControllers` get a storyboard ID. For what you're asking you can use the `tag` property.

Answer (score 1):

The storyboard ID is a string field that you can use to create new `UIViewController` (not `UIButton` or other elements). An example of how to use it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867565/what-is-a-storyboard-id-and-how-can-i-use-this).

Answer (score 0):

- only `View Controller` has `Storyboard ID`

  - [image: vs_has_storyboard_id]
- other view (eg: `UIButton`) no `Storyboard ID`

  - [image: view_no_storyboard_id]

## how get `id` of a normal view (in Storyboard) ?

two method:

### use `Referencing Outlet` = normally is weak reference ~= like `pointer` in `C`

eg: add reference for UIButton

in Storyboard -> choose your UIButton -> Right Click `UIButton` -> `Referencing Outlets`->`New Referencing Outlet` -> drag it to `ViewController.h` -> got notice `Insert Outlet` -> popup window -> set `Name` to you want, eg `deviceNameBtn` -> `Connect` -> auto generated code into `ViewController.h`

[image]

[image]

[image]

```objectivec
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *deviceNameBtn;
```

then in you (Objective-C) code, you can use `deviceNameBtn` as the `ID` of `UIButton`, do whatever you want

### use (`int` type) `tag`

eg: your `UILabel` view's `tag = 1`

[image: uilabel_tag_1]

get your view:

```objectivec
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```