# Navigation Controller crashing app

Tags: xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Within my app I have a UIViewController and a UITableViewController.

I wish to navigate from the UIViewController to the UITableViewController.

Within the UITableViewController I want a navigation bar so that I can 'add' items and declare when I am 'done' so that I can travel back to my UIViewController.

To achieve this I have embedded the UITableViewController within a UINavigationController as this reveals the navigation bar which I can add my buttons to and add a title.

I have 'control dragged' a segue from the UIViewController to the UINavigationController, which itself is attached to the UITableViewController.

```
UIViewController -> UINavigationController -> UITableViewController
```

My intended functionality is to travel from the UIViewController to the UITableViewController. However, the app crashes with the following message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',     reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7f96c1451890>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'UINavigationController-IxO-nE-zon'
```

The app does not crash if my segue is directly attached from the UIViewController to the UITableViewController (with the UINavigationController gone). However, then I do not get my Navigation Bar at the top of the UITableViewController which I need.

So my question is either: can I fix this error so that I can travel between them, or is there another way of doing this so that I can travel between them whilst keeping my navigation bar.

Thank you!

Comment: What if you embed the `UIViewController` in the navigation controller and then push the `UITableViewController `?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turned out I had the setup correct but I required a project clean before it worked. I guess because I added the storyboard ID's after adding the segues.

Thank-you to the following answer: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32679967/1060262)