# How to open a view from appdelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using custom URL scheme to open my app. 
My code below is used to open a view from the tabbar. But how should I open a specific view.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

if ([url.host  isEqual: @"main"]) 
{
    UITabBarController *tab = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    tab.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: are you using Storyboard?

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check url scheme as below :

```
 if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"main"]) {
       UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
       UITabBarController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarcontroller"]; // if you are use storyboard .
       [self.Window setRootViewController:rootViewController];
    }
```

Comment: how do I set the storyboard name and  identifier ?

Comment: you can set tabbar's storyboard id as below : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11604827/3901620

Comment: and story board name is that your storyboard file name. eg. Main.storyboard

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"main"]) {
       UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
       UITabBarController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarcontroller"]; // if you are use storyboard .
    tab.selectedIndex = 0;
       [self.Window setRootViewController:rootViewController];
    }
```