# IBOutlet button not working - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, iboutlet

I have searched for a similar question to this but cannot find it because mine is very obscure.

I am currently developing a social network app. All my code seems to be correct. However, there is the share button that is not working. I will attach the code here:

```
@IBOutlet weak var shareBtn: UIButton!
```

which is in one of my files to connect it up and:

```
@objc func toCreatePost (_ sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toCreatePost", sender: nil)
}
```

Before you ask, all of my segues are connected, the buttons are connected to the code and the identifier is correct.

I don't know if it could be an error in Xcode itself or my code, but the button clicks when it is run however it does not do anything. Help would be appreciated.
The error is that when the button is clicked it does not do anything and will not go to the next ViewController even though the code seems to be correct.

```
@IBAction func toCreatePost (_ sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toCreatePost", sender: nil)
}
```

Above is the code with an IBaction which I edited which now gives me a crash. The crash is a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Here is my main.storyboard

[image: main.storyboard image.]

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the action. Does your app halt when the button is pressed? If not, there *is* a problem with your target/action pattern.

Comment: Does `toCreatePost` get called (i.e. put a breakpoint or a `print` inside it)?

Comment: do you have a `shouldPerformSegue` or `performSegue` that makes it retrurn without performing the segue?

Comment: The toCreatePost is an identifier used in the storyboard where the shareBtn is connecting to the new screen

Comment: @rmaddy I have changed it to a IBAction. Then reconnected this to the shareBtn however I am getting a crash when this is done. Any ideas?

Comment: Please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295471/storyboard-doesnt-contain-a-view-controller-with-identifier

Comment: If there is a crash, please show the error message you get in console/debugguer.

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException . That is what is in the console @Larme

Comment: Full error message please. Starting from « Terminating with «  (with an uppercase)

Comment: My Bad there, didnt read upwards.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SocialApp.FeedVC shareBtn:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f88af50e7a0'

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: only put the relevant info in due to too many words @Larme

Comment: You don't have a IBAction method named `sharedBtn:`, is it `toCreatePost:`? Remove the connection from I guess the `var shareBtn` to the `shareBtn:` method in Interface Builder.

Comment: in "@objc func toCreatePost (_ sender: AnyObject) {...}" it seems like you're performing by adding a target check that method properly, it should work then

Answer (score 0):

[See this for view-based issues click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295471/storyboard-doesnt-contain-a-view-controller-with-identifier)

It seems you have not added navigation controller before the view controller from where you have to perform segua action.

if your problem still not resolved try to push manualy without segua

Comment: I will upload a screenshot of my main.storyboard.

Comment: Did you check by adding print method inside the action

Comment: just checked, get a crash Thread 1: signal SIGABRT before it can print.

Comment: Now check above link it is based on your problem

Comment: same error still. Tried cleaning my project before. Here is what is in the terminal                             libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException