# 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7b1800030960>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'GroupProfileViewController''

Tags: swift, storyboard, viewcontroller

```
fileprivate func showGroupProfile(_ item:HomescreenLongTapItem) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroupProfileViewController") as! GroupProfileViewController
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I need to change VC after press on icon in HomescreenLongTap but I recive that error 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'GroupProfileViewController'
I used the StoryboardID in my code.
How can I correctly navigate to next ViewController?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48612127/2395636).

Comment: I am voting to close this question as I asked the same question about 9 years ago. A simple google search would have found the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you set the identifier of the viewcontroller, lets say "GroupProfileViewController"
2. Make sure this code is **NOT** in `viewDidLoad()`. If you have, consider doing this in `viewDidAppear()`

Present the code like this example:

```
if let storyboard = storyboard{
   let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroupProfileViewController") as! GroupProfileViewController
   self.present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
    if let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "GroupProfileViewController") as? GroupProfileViewController {
         present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

in storyboard: --> in custom class give this viewcontroller class GroupProfileViewController

--> identity --> Storyboard ID (GroupProfileViewController) also give same name as class or your wish.